# Using CSS to define spacing between elements

Tags: html, css

I am not an html/css expert and have been trying to implement some best practices.  In a recent project I completed 90% of my`<h>, <div>, and <p>`tags (for example) have white spacing before or after the elements for appearance and the spacing varies often.  I recently began moving all of my inline styles to an external style sheet.  When the styles were inline, it was very clear how much space was between elements.  After moving them to external files, it's really unclear.  When looking at the html I don't know, "Does this `<div>` have spaces before or after it?  Does it get it's spacing from a base stylesheet?  Is it overridden in an other file?"

Therefor, I defined a few classes in my base css file:

```
.singleSpaceAfter
{
  padding-bottom:1em;
}
.singleSpaceBefore
{
  padding-top:1em;
}
.doubleSpaceAfter
{
  padding-bottom:1.5em;
}
.doubleSpaceBefore
{
  padding-top:1.5em;
}
```

I then apply this class in my `<div>, <p>, <h>` elements and it's
A) clear when space is present
B) Class names are ambiguous enough as to how-much space (padding-top:1em..1.1em, 1.2em..), so it's flexible.

On the premise that html is for content and css is for layout, is what I'm doing crazy?

My css files are very small and I like that.  If I have to specify the spacing for all my `<h>, <p> and <div>` tags by element id they are going to grow very large and complicated.

I haven't seen anybody else apply the method I used above, so I'm fairly confident that it violates some best practices but so far I like it and it works well for me.  I'm hoping for some sensible arguments as to why this is ok or not.

---

Thanks for all of your comments so far.  I do use Eric Meyer's CSS Reset (that i discovered from another stackoverflow post :-), but didn't think it relevant to my implementation.

As far as defining additional spacing/margin/padding in a base:  This feels like I would constantly (50% of the time) have to override them in additional css files.  I think this would lead to all sorts of "mystery" spacing.  And as far as styling each individual element by element id, it seems like it would be really messy.  I probably have 100+ div/p elements throughout and to define padding for everyone of them in a seperate file (each of them having one of two or three variations) just feels messy.  As well as it makes the html less descriptive.

The method i described seems to make the html very readable (no abiguity as far as where space comes from) and the css in total is ~20 lines.

Thanks for answering my question sincerly though.  I was expecting a few more noob references

Comment: If it's working for you, there's nothing wrong with it :)

Comment: You should be using Firebug or the dev tools built into a modern browser. You can right click and choose "inspect element" to see *exactly* what styles are active, and where they're coming from. This is a solved problem, and there's no excuse for not being aware of what style values an element has.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts, you can now edit your question / leave comments under answers you receive and accept an answer. Please consider associating an OpenID with your account to avoid this sort of disconnection in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/), then style the elements the way you want. This ensures things are consistent between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that class naming convention used frequently before and it always bothers me.  Now, this may come down to developer style and personal preference, but here's my reasoning.  As you stated HTML is for content, CSS is for visual design and layout.  So, using a class name that indicates the visual aspect of the content goes against that principle.

Instead, figure out *why* some paragraphs have more padding.  Perhaps, it is because the introduction text always is padded more.  Maybe sidebar paragraphs are always padded more than the main content.  If it is *truly* arbitrary, that seems strange to me.

Once you have determined the different types of content you have, then come up with appropriate class names.  You may find you don't even need to apply classes, and find you can use different selectors, possibly including:

```
.mainContent p:first-child
.sideBar p
.comment p
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be sensible to me.  I utilize a similar approach for font sizes and colors E.g. I have a textmed, textlarge, textxlarge, etc.  the key is that it is reusable, and uncomplicated.  As long as it is easy to maintain for you, then go with the approach.

I would caution, however, that different browsers render HTML differently, for example, the default padding and spacing between objects is different in IE vs. Gecko vs. tool kit.  To overcome this problem, I usually apply a global style *{padding:0px;margin:0px;} an unfortunate side effect, however, is the loss of default tabbing for UL tags

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to first use a CSS reset.  Due to different browsers all having different defaults for margin and padding among other things for each html tag.  A CSS reset starts all browsers off on the same foot.

From here you can declare some base styling for each of your elements.  Remember elements don't just have padding they also have margins.  Margins will also collpase together to form a single margin with the largest margin taking priority.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, its fine to do it this way, it doesn't violate best practices, and it makes your code very readable, which is an important factor in deciding what best practices are. There's nothing wrong with naming your classes in a way that makes sense. And, defining spacing using em's is handy for just this reason; it adjusts with your font-size.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see (not saying it's wrong) is, say, they tell you "can we add extra space in the help pages", then you would need to change all the help pages to, say, 'DoubleSpaceAfter', which kind of defeats one of the advantages of CSS.  If you could define the styles semantically, like 'help_header', 'help_text', etc. (not by ID, but by class, which would make it much more reusable) then you would only need to change the class style in the CSS file without touching the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for you then go for it. It is violating a few best practices though. I'd highly recommend a CSS Reset, such as [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and then applying your styles from there. I personally don't like having multiple classes per element unless absolutely necessary, but, as I said, if it works for you and no one tells you to change it then you CAN continue on that way. However, I would suggest you try out a reset and see how/if you like it because then you can style each element without having to worry about varying whitespace. And, if you don't like it, you can go back to what you're doing now.